# Laravel 5 validate string with multiple dates comma separated

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can i validate this string with the laravel validation? I want to check if the dates between the commas is a date.

2017-11-11,2017-12-11-2017,2017-13-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to your comment. Yes laravel can do that, by creating a request class like this.

```
<?php namespace App\Laravel\Requests\Backoffice;

use Session,Auth, Input;
use App\Laravel\Requests\RequestManager;

class DateRequest extends RequestManager{

    public function rules(){

        $rules = [
            //validate if the value is a date and check the date_format must be in "Y-d-m" form
            'date' => 'date|date_format:"Y-d-m"',
        ];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function messages(){
        return [
            'date' => "Invalid date.",
            'date_format' => "Invalid date format.",
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not validate dates between commas

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode() array function, It split a string and convert it to array.

```
    $date_string = '2017-11-11,2017-12-11-2017,2017-13-11';

    //Split the $date_string
    $dates = explode(',',$date_string);

    //get the values of the $dates variable
    foreach($dates as $date){

      //Check if the $date values are valid or not
      if(Carbon::createFromFormat('DATE FORMAT',$date) !== false){
         //valid date format
      }else{
         //invalid date format
      }

    }
```

Comment: you should not just post code, give some explanation, please.

Comment: I know i can solve it like this way, i mean is there a way do it the laravel way $this->validate($request, [  'datestring' => 'required', etc etc

Comment: Yes, you can try this by creating a request class like this.

<?php namespace App\Laravel\Requests\Backoffice;

use Session,Auth, Input;
use App\Laravel\Requests\RequestManager;

class DateRequest extends RequestManager{

 public function rules(){

  $rules = [
   'date' => "date_format:"d-m-Y"",
  ];

  return $rules;
 }

 public function messages(){
  return [
   'required' => "This field is required.",
  ];
 }
}

Comment: @Bas use Rule Objects as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using Rule Objects more elegant, next time you can reuse this validation/rule.

Run `php artisan make:rule Stringdate`

`app/Rules/Stringdate.php` file will be generated.

change passes method like this

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if(!$value){
            return false;
        }
        $dates = explode(',',$value);

        foreach ($dates as $date){

            if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date) < 1){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The validation you can make in controller, for ex.

```
$this->validate(request(),['data' => ['required',new Stringdate()]]);
```

(`data` is your *attribute name*)

Answer (score 0):

in that case you should create a custom validator for the comma delimiter date string so can still use the Request class.

```
public function validateSampleCustom($attribute, $value, $parameters){

        ...do you custom code here
        ...where value is the passed value from the input field
        ...parameters are the value after the semi_colon in your request eg : (sample_custom:param1,param2,...,paramn)

    }
```

i can show you some custom validator

```
public function validateOldPassword($attribute, $value, $parameters){

        if($parameters){
            $user_id = $parameters[0];
            $user = User::find($user_id);
            return Hash::check($value,$user->password);
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

I just want to clarify your concern so we can help you with your issues. and i use this to my Request class by calling it this way

```
'password' => "required|old_password",
```

and then to include the custom validator you should call the Validator::resolver in your AppServiceProvider to bind your custom validator.

```
public function boot()
    {
        // Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }
```